# Leaving succulents in the sun for 2 weeks without watering

Tags: watering, plant-care, succulents, sunlight

I'm about to leave for 2 weeks and the days are just stating to become sunny. I have a few succulents on a windowsill (on a south-facing window), and I'm wondering how they'll cope with this.

I watered them within the last 4 weeks, but I'm wondering if I should water them again just before leaving. I'm also asking myself if I should move them away from the direct sun. I have a feeling this might just be apprehension on my part, however, since the plants would be in the sun either way when I'm here.

Two of these succulents are Euphorbia, the rest are cacti, and there are a few aloe. Should I take special care for any of these?

Here's a picture:

[image: the plants on the windowsill]

Answer (score 3):

If this is their normal home by the window and you only water once a month, they should be fine. I would water them before leaving.  Leave that glass cage open. I would also have someone come over in a week to check on them to report on how they are doing.  How long have these succulents been in this spot? You said it has begun to be sunny so more infrared is getting in which is fine if they've been there for awhile.  They look beautiful.  A very cool 'hobby' and collection you've made...are those your own starts in the glass cage?

I'd water them before I left for sure. No fertilizer. I'd have a friend come over because I am paranoid about everything in my home when I am not there.  Probably not necessary.  Do you have those automatic lights and stop your newspaper delivery? I even have my radio turning on and off...and when away worrying will only ruin your vacation or trip.  Safe trip, Gabriele!

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to ask my flat mates to check. I bought these plants in the period between August and November last year, which means they haven't yet seen full sun for extended periods of time. That's part of the reason why I worry. But I'll be sure to water them before leaving and ask my flat mates to check :)

Comment: By the way: as far as I know euphorbia need water more often. Should I take special care of them?

Comment: Depends on what brand of Euphorbia.  How often do you water them normally?  I'd take them to a friend's home that you KNOW, same south facing window with watering instructions.  Do you, hopefully, use bottled water, not tap?

Comment: I couldn't see the thin skinned Euphorbia that needs more water. All your babies look like succulents, which of course you know store water.  You could put up a sun screen...purchase a chunk of 30% blocking black plastic sunscreen to use just while you are gone to make absolutely sure.  If they've been in this window they should be very used to the amount of light and hardened to the heat.  It would be the ambient heat of your home that would make a difference and succulents have evolved to deal with very high heat,but, like I said I'd be super cautious as well.  You are GREAT to care so much.

Comment: You could move the Euphorbia to the shaded corner?  I'd  be rotating your plants now and then anyhoo.  Have you been watering them more than the others?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't gotten around to using bottled water yet, I still use tap water (some of the plants developed a thin white film on their skin but I'm not sure if that's due to the water). The two thick-stemmed euphorbias I mentioned are shown in these questions: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/30812/16516 and http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/30458/16516. I do water them a little bit more frequently, but not much

Comment: Your point about the heat is very interesting, because the room does get very warm during the day, somewhere around 28 degrees Celsius around noon. I suppose that's fine for the plants, but I wonder if it makes them dry up faster.

Comment: That would be the problem, Gabriele!  That would dictate the need for a shade cloth on your window.  Do you feel okay about leaving your window cracked like that?  NICE windows, btw!

Comment: Maybe a light curtain will do the job? I just wouldn't want to stunt their growth since it's almost spring, but I also have no experience on whether that'll affect them at all.

Comment: I'm really just conflicted because I wouldn't normally have a curtain when I'm here, so it seems illogical that I'd have it in similar conditions when I'm not here. However the prospect of not being able to keep an eye on the plants seems like it would justify that.

Comment: I am just being overly cautious.  I just hate to give you information that would be wrong for your situation.  They really should be fine...this shade cloth is a cheap thing, you'd TAPE it or juryrig it to cover the window while you are gone.  There are different weaves of this stuff...this was but one idea, it is just like a light curtain.  YOU are the one making ME a worry wort!!  Grins!!  Do  you trust ANY of your flat mates? Just to check in once or twice?  They SHOULD be fine if you water before you leave.